# Formatação HTML

Tags: html

Estou com um probleminha referente a um código em HTML :

[image: Formulario]

Existe alguma possibilidade de quebrar a linha do formulário acima ?

**Código**

```
{
    head:"<style>
body {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 12pt;
    width: 210mm;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.logo>img{
    float:right;
    height:?IIF(cFilAnt == '0101', 50, 230)?px;
}

table, tr, td, th {
    border-width: thin; 
    border-style: solid;
    border-collapse: separate;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

th {
    background-color: #F0FFF0;
    white-space: nowrap
}

td {
    white-space: nowrap
}

tr {
    white-space: nowrap
    page-break-after: right
}

.itemTotal {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

tr>:first-child>:first-child {
    max-width:105mm;
    max-height:200px;
}

tr>:nth-child(7), tr>:nth-child(6), tr>:nth-child(5), tr>:nth-child(4), tr>:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

tbody>:last-child>:nth-child(6), tbody>:nth-last-child(2)>:nth-child(6), tbody>:nth-last-child(3)>:nth-child(6){
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.company {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fieldName {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.span2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 105mm;
}

.span3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150mm;
}

.pageBreak {
    page-break-after: auto;

}

body>:last-child .pageBreak {
    page-break-after: avoid;
}

.printButton {
    float:top;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: eeee00;
}

.midinfo {
    text-align:center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

table {
    width:210mm
}

@media print
{    

    @page {
       @bottom-left {
            content: counter(page) \"/\" counter(pages);
        }
     }
    .no-print, .no-print *
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
.supertable{
    border: 1px;
    width: 900mm;
    }


</style>",
    browser:"chrome.exe",
    iniBody:"<tr><table class=\"supertable\">
                <tfoot> 
                </tfoot>
                <tr class=\"supertable\"><td class=\"supertable\">
            </tr>   
            <div class=\"printButton, no-print\">
            <a href=\"javascript:window.print()\" rel=\"nofollow\"><img src=\"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-RDDqoEKk8ps/UtMe1KDXIJI/AAAAAAAA02A/EAxkZwdARz4/s1600/imprimir.png\" /></a></div>
            ",
    endBody:"",
    PEDIDO:"<span class=\"logo\"><img src=\"?SB1->(SmUriImage(GetMV('MV_LOGPDV'), 'logoPDV'))?\"/></span>
            <div class=\"company\">

                <div>?SmProper(oFil:Get('NOME'))?</div>
                <br/>
            </div>
                <div class=\"companyInfo\">
                <div><b>CNPJ:</b> ?SmProper(oFil:Get('CNPJ'))? - <b>I.E.:</b> ?SmProper(oFil:Get('IE'))?</div>
                <div>
                    <span><b>Endereço:</b> ?SmProper(oFil:Get('ENDERECO') + ' - ' + oFil:Get('BAIRRO') + ' - ' + oFil:Get('CIDADE') + ' - ' + oFil:Get('UF'))?</span> 

                </div>
                <div><b>Emails:</b> comercial@supri-medical.com  –  licitacao@supri-medical.com</div>
                <div>               consignado@supri-medical.com</div>
                <div><b>Telefone Comercial:</b> (31) 2516-8084 / 2555-9081 - <b>Whatsapp.:</b> (31) 99730-8390</div>
                <hr class=\"line\" #IIF(cFilAnt != '0101', 'width=\"80%\" align=\"left\"', '')#/>
            </div>",
    CABECALHO:" <br/>
                <span class=\"span2\"><b>DATA:</b> ?SC5->C5_EMISSAO?</div>
                <div><b>VENDEDOR(A):</b> ?SmProper(Posicione('SA1', 1, SC5->C5_VEND1, 'A1_NOME'))?</div>
                <br/>
                <div><span><b>FANTASIA:</b> ?SmProper(SA1->A1_NREDUZ)?</span></div>
                <div><span><b>CPF/CNPJ:</b> ?JustChars(SA1->A1_CGC, '0123456789-')?</span><span class=\"span2\"><b>I.E.:</b> ?JustChars(SA1->A1_INSCR, '0123456789-')?</span></div>
                <div><span><b>END.:</b> ?SmProper(SA1->A1_END)?</span><span class=\"span2\"><b>CEP:</b> ?JustChars(SA1->A1_CEP, '0123456789-')?</span></div>
                <div><span><b>BAIRRO:</b> ?SmProper(SA1->A1_BAIRRO)?</span><span class=\"span2\"><b>CIDADE:</b> ?SmProper(SA1->A1_MUN) + ' - ' + SmProper(SA1->A1_EST)?</span></div>
                <div><span><b>TEL.:</b> ?SmProper(SA1->A1_FONE)?</span><span class=\"span2\"><b>CEL.:</b> ?SmProper(SA1->A1_CELULAR)?</span></div>
                <div><span><b>EMAIL:</b> ?Lower(SA1->A1_EMAIL)?</span><span class=\"span2\"><b>CONTATO:</b> ?SmProper(SA1->A1_CONTATO)? </span><span class=\"span3\"><b>CONTATO 2: </b>?SmProper(SC5->C5_CONTATO)?</span></div>
                <br/>
                <br/>",
    ITENS:{
            OPEN:"<table>
                        <tr>
                        <th><div class=\"fieldName\">ITEM</div></th>
                        <th><div class=\"fieldName\">CÓDIGO.</div></th>
                        <th><div class=\"fieldName\">DESCRIÇÃO DO PRODUTO.</div></th>
                        <th><div class=\"fieldName\">QTDE.</div></th>
                        <th><div class=\"fieldName\">MARCA.</div></th>
                        <th><div class=\"fieldName\">ANVISA.</div></th>
                        <!--<th><div class=\"fieldName\">UN.</div></th>-->
                        <th><div class=\"fieldName\">PREÇO UNIT.</div></th>
                        <th><div class=\"fieldName\">VALOR TOTAL.</div></th>
                        </tr>",     
            CLOSE:"<tr>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td>
                        <div class=\"itemTotal\">?nQuant?</div>
                        </td>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td>
                            <div class=\"itemTotal\">Sub Total:
                        <td/>   
                            <div class=\"itemTotal\"><b>R$ </b>?ApplyPict('C5_VALBRUT',, SC5->(C5_VALBRUT + C5_VALDESC))?</div>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td>
                            <div class=\"itemTotal\">Desconto:</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class=\"itemTotal\"><b>R$ </b>?ApplyPict('C5_VALDESC')?</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td>
                            <div class=\"itemTotal\">Total Líquido:</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>                        
                            <div class=\"itemTotal\"><b>R$ </b>?ApplyPict('C5_VALBRUT')?</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br/>"
            },
    ITEM:"<tr>
                    <td>?SmProper(SC6->C6_ITEM)?</td>
                    <td>?SmProper(SB1->B1_CODPROD)?</td>
                    <td><p>?SmProper(SB1->B1_OBSCOM)?<br/></p></td>
                    <td>?SC6->C6_QUANT?</td>
                    <td>?SmProper(SC6->C6_OBS)?</td>
                    <td>?SmProper(SB1->B1_CODANV)?</td>
                    <td><b>R$ </b>?ApplyPict('C6_PRCUNI')?</td>
                    <td><b>R$ </b>?ApplyPict('C6_TOTAL')?</td>
        </tr>",
    RODAPE:"<p>
            <div>
                <b>PRAZO DE ENTREGA:</b> ATÉ 3 DIAS ÚTEIS APÓS EMISSÃO
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <b>CONDIÇÃO DE PAGTO:</b> 
                ?SE6->E6_DESCRI?
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div>
            <b>FORMA DE PAGTO:</b> ?SmProper(Posicione('SEA', 1, SC5->C5_NUM, 'EA_DESCRI'))?
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div><b>FRETE:</b> ?GetCmbDsc(, 'C5_TPFRETE', SC5->C5_TPFRETE) + '  ' + IIF(SC5->C5_TPFRETE=='1', 'POR CONTA DO REMETENTE', 'POR CONTA DO DESTINATÁRIO')?</div>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <b>OBSERVAÇÃO:</b> 
                ?SC5->C5_MENNOTA?
                ?SmProper(Posicione('SM4', 1, SC5->C5_MENPAD1, 'M4_FORMULA'))?
                ?SmProper(Posicione('SM4', 1, SC5->C5_MENPAD2, 'M4_FORMULA'))?
                ?SmProper(Posicione('SM4', 1, SC5->C5_MENPAD3, 'M4_FORMULA'))?
                ?SmProper(Posicione('SM4', 1, SC5->C5_MENPAD4, 'M4_FORMULA'))?
            </div>
            </p><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>


<div class=\"pageBreak\"></div></td></tr></table>"
}
```

Comment: A tabela eh preenchida na mão ou vem do Banco ? Pq vc não limita a largura da tabela não pode?

Comment: @hugocsl a tabela quebraria normalmente, só que o CSS do autor está "proibindo" isso. É um problema que o próprio autor criou.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer o que mostra [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14176610/5331941) à uma pergunta similar no Stack Overflow em inglês:

> Você pode fazer isso por setar um `width` para a tabela e você também pode usar
>
> ```
> word-wrap:break-word;
> ```
>
> para evitar que palavras muito longas ultrapassem os limites da tabela.
>
> É mais interessante setar o `width` num CSS:
>
> Editado para incluir
>
> ```
> table-layout:fixed;
> ```
>
> no CSS abaixo
>
> Exemplo: http://jsbin.com/atonut/1/edit
>
> ```
> table {
> width:500px;
> table-layout:fixed;
> }
>
>
> td {
> word-wrap:break-word;
> }
> ```
>
> Se seu problema é a quantidade de texto e não necessariamente palavras longas,
>   use apenas `width`, and deixe a palavra "quebrar" automaticamente.

Espero que isso ajude.